# Python script that increases a number by a percent

Tags: python, math

So, I've been working on this project for quite a while, and I can't seem to figure this out. I've written the script for increasing a number by a percent, but I keep getting this error:

```
File "C:\Users\jacob\Python Scripts\Percent.py", line 11, in <module>
    value = str(num + ((num / 100) * percent))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

I don't know why this is happening, but here's my code.

```
value = ""
print("Number increase or decrease by percent")
print("")
print("Increase or decrease:") 
input = input()
if (input == "increase"):
    print("Number:") 
    num = input()
    print("Percent:") 
    percent = input()
    value = str(num - ((num / 100) * percent))
    print(value)
if (input == "decrease"):
    print("Number:") 
    num = input()
    print("Percent:") 
    percent = input()
    value = str(num - ((num / 100) * percent))
    print(value)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm still a noob.

Comment: `input()` returns a string, so you'd have to convert the value to an integer before doing math on it.

Comment: Also, I don't see how this can be your real code, because the fifth line `input = input()` will replace _the input function itself_, and any further calls to `input()` would produce an error, because `input` is now a string and not a function anymore.

Answer (score 0):

`if` statements do not need parentheses in Python.  Also, don't repeat yourself.  You had identical code in both branches.  And if you're doing a multiply and a divide, do them in that order to avoid loss of precision.  Also, when you're increasing by a percentage, you generally want to add, not subtract.

```
print("Number increase or decrease by percent")
print("")
print("Increase or decrease:") 
option = input()
print("Number:") 
num = int(input())
print("Percent:") 
percent = int(input())
if option == "increase":
    value = num + (num * percent / 100)
if option == "decrease":
    value = num - (num * percent / 100)
print(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

`input()` returns a string, you have to convert the input string to `float`, and you should not let `input = input()`. The code below should work:

```
value = ""
print("Number increase or decrease by percent")
print("")
print("Increase or decrease:") 
option = input()
if (option == "increase"):
    print("Number:") 
    num = float(input())
    print("Percent:") 
    percent = float(input())
    value = str(num + ((num / 100) * percent))
    print(value)
if (option == "decrease"):
    print("Number:") 
    num = float(input())
    print("Percent:") 
    percent = float(input())
    value = str(num - ((num / 100) * percent))
    print(value)
```